# Connecting to a Postgres database with Django and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble with connecting to a Postgres database in a Django Python app. It seems to be using the sqlalchemy library and trying to connect to `postgresql+pg8000://username:password@46.195.0.100:5432/dbname?ssl=True`. The error I get from Django is the following: `TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl'`

When I tried removing the `ssl=True` from the database URL, I got the following error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pg8000.exceptions.InterfaceError) {'S': 'FATAL', 'V': 'FATAL', 'C': '28000', 'M': 'no pg_hba.conf entry for host "51.2.345.678", user "upeducation", database "upeducationnetwork", SSL off', 'F': 'auth.c', 'L': '489', 'R': 'ClientAuthentication'}
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
```

I'm doubly confused because I have no idea what that host is in the message: `'no pg_hba.conf entry for host "51.2.345.678"`

Even though it seems like Django is routing through something else while trying this locally, I'm able to connect to the database with and without SSL on my local machine with a SQL client.

Comment: Make sure you're using SQLAlchemy 1.4+ and the latest pg8000 version. SQLAlchemy only supports pg8000 from 1.4 onwards.

Comment: Yep, the app meets those requirements. Sqlalchemy is 1.4.2 and pg8000 is on 1.16.6

Comment: The parameter `ssl=True` should instead be `ssl_context=True`. Also, the latest version of pg8000 is 1.19.4.

Comment: I'd suggest forgetting about Django and SQLAlchemy for a moment and just seeing if you can connect with just pg8000. Here's an example https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#basic-example

Comment: Doesn't seem like this is even using pg8000 actually and instead `sqlalchemy` and `records`